# How to pass JavaScript GetElementById string value to Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a method to translate different strings in Product class from English language to another. It has two variables: string and language. And for the first one I expect to get current value of the text area. Here how it looks like in JS:

```
var primary_value = document.getElementById('primary_body_html_value').getElementsByClassName('note-editable')[0].innerText;
```

And then I want to use this method inside JS function:

```
var translated_string = "<%= GoogleTranslator.translate(primary_value, 'de') %>"
```

The main question is how can use this 'primary_value' inside 'translated_string'? As I know - I can use Ajax but I am a bit new to this and I don't understand how to write correctly a method for Ajax and for Product controller. In case if you need a controller code:

```
class ProductsController < AuthenticatedController
  before_action :set_product, only: %i[show edit update]

  def index
    if params.include?('id')
      redirect_to edit_product_path(params[:id]) and return
    end
  end

  def edit
    redirect_to products_path, error: 'product not found' unless @product
    render :edit_polaris
  end

  def update
    if @product.update(product_params)
      render json: {
        status: :ok,
        notice: 'Saved successfully!'
      }, status: 200
    else
      render json: {
        status: :error,
        error: 'Something Went Wrong'
      }, status: 400
    end
  end

  private

  def product_params
    params.permit(
      :id,
      primary_locale: {},
      locales: {}
    )
  end

  def set_product
    @product = Product.find(product_params[:id])
  end
end
```

Comment: If you just want to translate value in your JS code, you can use some JS library instead of using the ruby method. If you still want to call a ruby method using JS, you can use `js.erb` file extension.

Comment: As I said - I already can use Ruby method inside JS. Like here:
var translated_string = "<%= GoogleTranslator.translate(primary_value, 'de') %>"
The only question is how can put this 'primary_value' inside Ruby method? Because I want to get document.GetElementById string value but I don't know how to send it to Rails.

Comment: Ohh okay got it, then you will have to make an ajax call in that case. You can refer to this SO answer for more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/14080273

Comment: I saw this one but anyway - thank you. I just don't understand - how can I write the correct controller method for this? Like, I need to add new product_param to my ProductsController? I would be really grateful for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a sketch but hopefully can help you out.
It can be inside one of your existing controller methods, for the sake of the example lets say you added a route (and controller method) called translated_string to ProductsController.

```
#ProductsController
 
def translated_string
   primary_value = params[:primary_value]
   @translated_string = GoogleTranslator.translate(primary_value, 'de')
   render json: {translated_string: @translated_string}
end
```

Now when something happens on your DOM page where primary_value is set, you send primary_value via ajax to translated_string and you get the json response with the translated string back - u can do whatever you want with it. This is just an example, there are a million ways to go about it, hope this gives you a direction.