# Setting a Ruby Variable inside Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby varibale 
`$text = "abcd"`
I have some condition inside my jquery according to which this text should change.
This is so far i have tried.. but no luck.

```
$("#xyz").click(function() {
  new_text = 'efgh';
  "<% $text = new_text %>"
}
```

Is this possible. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ruby is server side... you can't do something like that unless using ajax...

Comment: but i can set a string directly.. if that is possible i can pass new_text right?

Comment: The code inside <%  %> will only execute at load time..

Comment: Indirectly you can achieve this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959770/how-to-pass-a-javascript-variable-into-a-erb-code-in-a-js-view/14643289#14643289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT - Realize this is the opposite of what you want! instead of deleting, it may help someone so I'll leave...

--

You could use the [`gon` gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon) ([Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript)) -

```
#Gemfile
gem 'gon', '~> 5.0.4'

#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
class YourController < ApplicationController
   def method
      gon.push({
          var_name: "value"
      })
   end
end

#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
...
<%= include_gon %>

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
alert(gon.var_name);
```

Comment: No problem - hope it helps!