# How to pass javascript variable to rails partial view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I got a situation, there is a Javascript variable I need pass to rails partial view.

For example in **test.html.erb**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var array  =  <%= raw sort_section %>
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        $('#test').append("<%= j render :partial => 'section_in_panel', :locals => {:section => raw array[i]} %>");
    }
</script>
```

But it keep throwing syntax error, I have try many ways like

```
{:section => j sort_section_js[i]} %>"
{:section =>" + sort_section_js[i] + "}%>"
```

I need to use that because I want to call `ajax` to change `array` dynamically.

### Update

So, maybe I need to write a controller

```
def get_new_variable
    ...
    return new_variable
end
```

Then in the **test.html.erb**

```
<script>
$('test').onclick(function(event) {
   //write some ajax call
   //get new_variable
   $('#test').empty();
   $('#test').append("<%= j render :partial => 'section_in_panel', :locals => {:section => raw new_variable} %>");
  });
)</script>
```

Is that right direction?

Comment: what does `sort_section_js` hold?

Comment: It hold a nested array, sorry I forgot to change the variable name.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959770/how-to-pass-a-javascript-variable-into-a-erb-code-in-a-js-view

Comment: Javascript is run on the client after ruby renders the view on the server, then you can't pass the value of javascript variable to rails partial view.

Comment: I get it, so the only way is to write a new controller to get new variable, and then pass the new variable to partial view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alberto Juan wrote in comment, you can't use javascript variable in ruby code.
Ruby code will be interpreted before javascript and will not know what is the i.

Update: Your update will not work either as your using new_variable you get in your javascript code.

For using partial after ajax call, follow instructions in this **[link](https://coderwall.com/p/kqb3xq/rails-4-how-to-partials-ajax-dead-easy)**

#### Example:

**items/index.html.erb**

```
<div class="grid">
  <% @categories.each do |cat| %>
    <%= link_to cat.name, fetch_items_path(:cat_id => cat.id), :remote => true %>
  <% end %>

  <%= render partial: 'item_grid', locals: { items: @items} %>
</div>
```

**routes.rb**

```
get "/fetch_items" => 'items#from_category', as: 'fetch_items'
```

**items_controller.rb**

```
def index
    @items = Item.all
    @categories = Category.all
end

def from_category
    @selected = Item.where(:category_id => params[:cat_id])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

**views/items/from_category.js.erb**

```
$("#items_grid").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'items_list', locals: { items: @selected } ) %>");
```

Comment: Great practice! After I did this tiny practice, I got the right direction to finish my project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use gem `gon` or simply do something like this:

```
<script>
  MyVars[:someVar] = <%= some_value %>;
</script>
```

But, I recommend you to separate your backend an frontend code and use JSON for passing data to JS.

Comment: But it's the other direction. They want to pass data _from_ JS.

Comment: Yep. It's my fail.