# Getting an erb file to call a method in a ruby class

Tags: javascript, ruby, erb

My .erb file has a javascript script in it which receives how far the user has scrolled on a webpage. I need to send this information to a method Ruby Class which is in a different directory, but I don't know how to access it. Am I going about this in the right way?

```
require '../jobs/my_barchart_job.rb'
<% content_for :title do %>My super sweet dashboard<% end %>
<script>
        window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
        function myFunction() {
          object = MyBarchartJob.new
          object.accessFunction(document.body.scrollTop)
          console.log(document.body.scrollTop)
        }
    </script>

class MyBarchartJob
def accessFunction(variable)
   console.log(variable); 
end

end
```

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand your question, but this sounds impossible. ERB doesn't let you run Ruby code from javascript, it is just a templating language that provides a convenient way to generate text via Ruby.

Comment: You can use a js.erb file to put embedded ruby into javascript and use escape javascript to render regular erb partials, however, I am not totally certain what you are trying to do, but I get the impression that you may want to use ajax if you attempting to a use a server side ruby method with client side javascript. See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959770/how-to-pass-a-javascript-variable-into-a-erb-code-in-a-js-view